# Reference request: Lebesgue/Sobolev spaces on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, trace-map, besov-space

I am interested in the Boundary Lebesgue/Sobolev/Besov Spaces $L^p(\partial\Omega;\mathcal{H}^{N-1}), \ W^{k,p}(\partial\Omega),\ B^{s,p}(\partial\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain.

I found in the book of *Geovanni Leoni - A first course in Sobolev spaces* brief definitions of them.

**I wonder if there is any reference where they are treated as a central subject, and we can find the proofs of their properties (e.g. how to prove that they are Banach spaces, are they reflexive?, compactness results, and other properties)**